# Don't convert > to &gt; in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have some XML that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <![CDATA[
    > foo 
    ]]>
</root>
```

(Note the > sign in "> foo") and an XSLT stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <foo><xsl:value-of select='.'/></foo>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run `xsltproc stylesheet.xsl data.xml` I get

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>

    &gt; foo

</foo>
```

but the output I want is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>

    > foo

</foo>
```

i.e. keep the ">" as it is instead of converting it to an entity. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: with `>` it would be invalid as XML.

Comment: @khachik, not true; see my answer.

Comment: @khachik The W3C XML validator agrees with LarsH, the desired output is valid XML.

Comment: @pafcu never thought that it would be haskell code. Was thinking on entities in general. `>` is valid, but `<` would be **not well-formed**.

Comment: @pafcu, I'm curious, how did you get the W3C XML validator to check XML well-formedness? I can only get it to validate HTML/XHTML. Maybe I have the wrong URL? http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Comment: @LarsH: I just copied it into the input box and clicked check. "This document was successfully checked as well-formed XML!".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Oded, @khachik,

Try [checking his desired output for well-formedness](http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/). It is indeed well-formed XML. ("Valid" is not even a question here, as there is no schema.)

It is a common misconception that ">" is not legal in well-formed XML.
In most contexts, "<" is not legal, but ">" is legal everywhere with one rare exception. The [relevant paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) of the spec:

> The ampersand character (&) and the
>   left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear
>   in their literal form, except when
>   used as markup delimiters, or within a
>   comment, a processing instruction, or
>   a CDATA section. If they are needed
>   elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using
>   either numeric character references or
>   the strings " & " and " < "
>   respectively. The **right angle bracket
>   (>) may** be represented using the
>   string " &gt; ", and MUST, for
>   compatibility, be escaped using either
>   " &gt; " or a character reference **when
>   it appears in the string " ]]> " in
>   content,** when that string is not
>   marking the end of a CDATA section.

With XSLT 2.0, the "right" way to do what you want is to use `<xsl:character-map>`.
With XSLT 1.0, I think the only way to force the use of ">" in the output is to use **disable-output-escaping**, as @khachik suggested. Note however that XSLT processors are [not required to honor DOE or character maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#parsing-and-serialization), and some can't (e.g. if they're in a pipeline and are not connected to serialization). But you probably know by now whether yours can, and if it can't, you'll need to handle serialization issues at the end of the pipeline.

**However,** it is worth asking, **why** do you want the ">" serialized as ">"? As seen in the spec, &gt; is a perfectly acceptable way to express exactly the same information as far as XML is concerned. No downstream XML consumer should know the difference or care. Do you want it for aesthetic reasons?

**Update:** the OP wants that because the output needs to be not only well-formed XML, it also needs to be well-formed Literate Haskell.

Comment: The output is supposed to be Literate Haskell which requires that lines containing executable program code starts with the literal character ">" while everything else is seen as comments. The Literate Haskell parser knows nothing about XML or that &gt; and > are equivalent in XML.

Comment: @LarsH what is valuable in your answer?

Comment: @khachik: No, I document my code in a terse form with XML, which I then covnert to XHTML via XSLT.

Comment: @LarsH: When using `method="text"` the elements seem to be stripped, i.e. I don't get `<foo>` or `</foo>` in the output. I do care about XML in the output since it's supposed to be XHTML which is XML. The output is both valid XHTML _and_ valid Haskell, which is the entire point of literate Haskell.

Comment: @khachik: I see your point about the value of my answer with regard to the OP's task. However I believe it's valuable because (1) it helps stop further propagation of the widespread myth that ">" is not allowed in well-formed XML (valuable to readers in general); and (2) it gives the OP direction that the problem can be solved within the bounds of well-formed XML... which could be important to his downstream processes, and which will help him work *with* XML instead of against it.

Comment: I am the OP, and I agree that LarsH post was helpful :-)

Comment: @pafcu: ok... I was confused by your comments. "The output is supposed to be Literate Haskell" but it's also supposed to be XML, which you will later convert to XHTML, is that right? So it has to satisfy both XML constraints and the LH parser's constraints. In that case no, you can't use method="text"... you have to use d-o-e if your XSLT version is 1.0.

Comment: @LarsH: Just to clarify: the input is literate haskell which is also valid XML which includes comments and stuff like that. The output is literal haskell which is also valid XHTML which includes comments in a prettier way than in the input. So it is really a "comment-formatter". But this really is not so important for the problem itself, just an interesting detail.

Answer (score 4):

**Adding to the very good explanation of @LarsH**:

**If your XSLT processor allows [DOE](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping), then you can use**:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <foo><xsl:value-of select='.' disable-output-escaping="yes"/></foo>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <![CDATA[
    > foo
    ]]>
</root>
```

**the wanted output is produced**:

```
<foo>
    > foo
    </foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:value-of select='.' disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` but it wouldn't be well-formed XML.

**Update** With `>` it will be well formed. (With `<` it won't.)

Comment: I confess that I downvoted your answer because of the incorrect part about '>' not being well-formed XML. I wish I could remove that downvote, or else add an upvote, because of the useful suggestion to use d-o-e. However it won't let me, unless you edit your answer. If you do, let me know so I can change my vote.

Comment: @LarsH I updated my answer to be correct. You don't need to up-vote it, because it was down-voted correctly, `>` doesn't make XML not well-formed (and the "invalid" word wasn't correct in this context). Thank you :)