# Cycle through a list of html files with button

Tags: javascript, html, cycle

I have a list of products say:

```
laptops/prod1.html
laptops/prod2.html
laptops/prod3.html
monitors/prod1.html
monitors/prod2.html
monitors/prod3.html
```

I would like a button on my page that 'cycles' through the available items.

No idea how to do this. Is this possible with javascript?

Comment: What do you mean?  Like a drop down list with hyperlinks?

Comment: no just a button, that would take you to the next prod. or previous prod.

Comment: Are you showing the pages in an iframe or bringing in the content into a div or wanting an entire page load? You need to be more specific as these details make a difference. Where is the button? What have you tried so far?

Comment: 1) Are you trying to change a whole page 2) Are those just template html, meaning can they just be inserted into the body of a main page 3) Do you want to use iframes... need some actual code to help you. (See a theme here?)

Comment: -ninja -Yeah I see the theme. in over my head on this one!
-scrapp trying to change the whole page. (for now)

don't want to use iframes

Comment: Then you'd be better to just link the pages to each other ie page1 has a button that goes to page 2, page2 to page 3 and so on.  It makes more sense - no need to be clever with code.

Comment: Yes Mat - although I was thinking maybe there is a faster way using a list in xml file or something?

Comment: right now I am using a xsl with an xml data source to make the html for about 45 different products, in say 3 categories -15 product per category

II basically need them to link to the sku before and the sku after.

Comment: You would probably be better off using a div method where each page isn't a complete page but a scrap of html that you can inject into a div on a master page. Then you can track which page is present, what the next page is, and then load the content into the div. The loading would be done via ajax and I would strongly suggest using jQuery (or a similar lib) for that.

Comment: scrapp takes the take- but i have no idea how to do that. I'm mostly hack by night kind of a guy. any step by step tutorials you can recommend?

Comment: other than that I think I will just go with a drop down list or something. I will look into the suggested solutions. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextProduct(incr) {
  var href = window.location.href
    , offset = (typeof(incr)==='undefined' ? 1 : incr);
  window.location = href.replace(/(\d+)\.html/, function(m, g1) {
    return (Number(g1) + offset) + '.html'
  });
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var button;
button = document.getElementByID('next-button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() { nextProduct(1); });
button = document.getElementByID('prev-button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() { nextProduct(-1); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup a main page, this should not be a static html page but in your server side language of choice.

Include jquery to a main page using a script tag (you can get jquery from http://jquery.com/).

Your html could look like this:

```
<div id='content'></div>
<div>
   <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='prev' class='btn'>Previous</a>
   <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='next' class='btn'>Next</a>
</div>
```

In your js file you would have something like this:

```
var currPage = 0;
var pageList = ["laptops/prod1.html","laptops/prod2.html", "laptops/prod3.html"];
var totalPages = pageList.length;
$(".btn").on("click",function(){
   //if we are at the last page set currpage = 0 else increment currPage.
   currPage = currPage < (totalPages - 1) ? ++currPage : 0;
   var page = pageList[currPage];
   $('#content').load(currPage);
});
```

Some points to consider:

1. You will want to decide if the first page gets loaded on the main page load or on click
2. You will need to set a js variable to keep track of the currently loaded page
3. You will need to add some method of storing all the possible pages (think an array). This can get printed out to a script tag on the page on page load.
4. You need to decide what happens when you hit the end of the line. You can either cycle around or grey out the appropriate link.

[jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
[jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: xsltproc fails because of the < in line 6 of the js:
    currPage = currPage < (totalPages - 1) ? ++currPage : 0;

Comment: I'm not familiar with xsltproc but you *should* be able to escape the character.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248230/dont-convert-to-gt-in-xslt this might help with the escape